# Run Functional Tests - Unable to get teamfoundation Collection Uri

Tags: azure-devops

I am getting the following error with the "Run Functional Tests" task during a RELEASE task.

I am trying to run a unit test dll using the builtin VS .net test framework written in .Net 4.6.1 C# (VS2015.Update2)

The reason for running the tests on a VM is for scenarios that don't work on the 
Hosted Test agent

**Scenario**

Azure VM
UnitTests dll

**RELEASE Tasks**

Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment (Success)

Azure File Copy (Succes)

Run Functional Tests (Fails)

**LOG**

```
> 2016-04-14T01:42:49.2222367Z Executing the powershell script:
> C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.97.1\tasks\RunVisualStudioTestsusingTestAgent\1.0.32\RunDistributedTests.ps1
> 2016-04-14T01:42:50.5719493Z ##[debug]Entering script
> RunDistributedTests.ps1 2016-04-14T01:42:50.5749473Z
> ##[debug]TestMachineGroup = xxxx.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com
> 2016-04-14T01:42:50.5759489Z ##[debug]Test Drop Location =
> C:\AcceptanceTests\SampleWebApiE2ERelease 2016-04-14T01:42:50.5759489Z
> ##[debug]Source Filter = bin\Release\AcceptanceTest.dll 2016-04-14T01:42:50.5769483Z ##[debug]Test Filter Criteria = 
> 2016-04-14T01:42:50.5779473Z ##[debug]RunSettings File =
> C:\a\2c16ad4c2\CI Build\drop\AcceptanceTest\AcceptanceTest.runsettings
> 2016-04-14T01:42:50.5779473Z ##[debug]Build Platform = 
> 2016-04-14T01:42:50.5789483Z ##[debug]Build Configuration = 
> 2016-04-14T01:42:50.5789483Z ##[debug]CodeCoverage Enabled = false
> 2016-04-14T01:42:50.5799482Z ##[debug]TestRun Parameters to override =
> 2016-04-14T01:42:50.5799482Z ##[debug]TestConfiguration = 
> 2016-04-14T01:42:50.5829484Z ##[debug]Application Under Test Machine
> Group =  2016-04-14T01:42:50.6079488Z ##[debug]Loading module from
> path
> 'C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.97.1\agent\worker\Modules\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Common\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Common.dll'.
> 2016-04-14T01:42:50.6479489Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet
> 'Complete-Task'. 2016-04-14T01:42:50.6489487Z ##[debug]Importing
> cmdlet 'Get-LocalizedString'. 2016-04-14T01:42:50.6499484Z
> ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Set-TaskVariable'. 2016-04-14T01:42:50.6499484Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet
> 'Set-TaskProgress'. 2016-04-14T01:42:50.6509481Z ##[debug]Importing
> cmdlet 'Add-TaskIssue'. 2016-04-14T01:42:50.6509481Z
> ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Write-TaskDetail'. 2016-04-14T01:42:50.6519486Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Find-Files'.
> 2016-04-14T01:42:50.6719494Z ##[debug]Loading module from path
> 'C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.97.1\agent\worker\Modules\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.dll'.
> 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1184496Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet
> 'Add-BuildAttachment'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1194518Z ##[debug]Importing
> cmdlet 'Convert-String'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1204518Z
> ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Get-IndexedSourceFilePaths'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1204518Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet
> 'Get-JavaDevelopmentKitPath'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1214490Z
> ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Get-MSBuildLocation'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1214490Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet
> 'Get-ServiceEndpoint'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1224478Z ##[debug]Importing
> cmdlet 'Get-TfsClientCredentials'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1224478Z
> ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Get-ToolPath'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1234489Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Get-TaskVariable'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1234489Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet
> 'Get-VisualStudioPath'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1244823Z
> ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Get-VssConnection'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1244823Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Invoke-Ant'.
> 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1255789Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet
> 'Invoke-BatchScript'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1255789Z ##[debug]Importing
> cmdlet 'Invoke-Maven'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1266037Z ##[debug]Importing
> cmdlet 'Invoke-MSBuild'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1266037Z
> ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Invoke-PublishSymbols'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1276045Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Invoke-Tool'.
> 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1276045Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet
> 'Invoke-VSTest'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1286046Z ##[debug]Importing
> cmdlet 'Publish-BuildArtifact'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1286046Z
> ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Copy-BuildArtifact'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1296014Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet
> 'Add-BuildArtifactLink'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1296014Z
> ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Register-XamarinLicense'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1306047Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet
> 'Unregister-XamarinLicense'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.1306047Z
> ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Get-X509Certificate'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.3085527Z ##[debug]Loading module from path
> 'C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.97.1\agent\worker\Modules\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DTA\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DTA.dll'.
> 2016-04-14T01:42:51.4288417Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet
> 'Invoke-DeployTestAgent'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.4298713Z
> ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Invoke-RunDistributedTests'. 2016-04-14T01:42:51.4318712Z ##[debug]Getting the connection object
> 2016-04-14T01:42:51.6626731Z ##[debug]UnregisterTestAgent script Path 
> =  2016-04-14T01:42:51.6626731Z ##[debug]Calling Invoke-RunDistributedTests 2016-04-14T01:42:51.7435357Z
> ##[debug]Invoking Run Distributed Tests with Register Environment support 2016-04-14T01:42:52.5708848Z ##[warning]For troubleshooting,
> refer http://aka.ms/remotevstest. 2016-04-14T01:42:52.6509473Z
> ##[error]System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to get teamfoundation Collection Uri. Contact your administrator for more
> information. 2016-04-14T01:42:52.6519461Z ##[error]   at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.RunTests.Run()
> 2016-04-14T01:42:52.6529465Z ##[error]   at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.TaskRunner.Run(Dictionary`2
> arguments, VssConnection connection, TaskType taskType)
> 2016-04-14T01:42:52.6529465Z ##[error]   at
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.RundistributedTestsCmdLet.ProcessRecord()
```

**UPDATE - Added Screenshot**

[image]

**UPDATE 2 - More Details**

The Azure VM is not on a domain, its in a WORKGROUP

**UPDATE 3 - Recreated as a BUILD task**

I created a new BUILD with a single task "Run Functional Tests".
A similar error occurred.

[image: BUILD Task]

**BUILD COMPLETE LOG**

```
2016-04-19T21:51:19.2143997Z Entering OnPrepareEnvironment
2016-04-19T21:51:19.2613857Z Primary repository: SampleWebApiE2ERelease
2016-04-19T21:51:19.2643916Z Calculating build folder hash key.
2016-04-19T21:51:19.2683854Z Loading tracking config if exists: C:\a\SourceRootMapping\0898c6c5-1b24-4adf-945a-6859faaaf010\8\SourceFolder.json
2016-04-19T21:51:19.2703915Z Creating new tracking config.
2016-04-19T21:51:19.2719613Z Loading top-level tracking config if exists: C:\a\SourceRootMapping\Mappings.json
2016-04-19T21:51:19.2752569Z Writing config to file: C:\a\SourceRootMapping\Mappings.json
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3362720Z Writing config to file: C:\a\SourceRootMapping\0898c6c5-1b24-4adf-945a-6859faaaf010\8\SourceFolder.json
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3452728Z Checking if artifacts directory exists: C:\a\1\a
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3452728Z Creating artifacts directory.
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3462731Z Checking if test results directory exists: C:\a\1\TestResults
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3472726Z Creating test results directory.
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3482737Z Creating binaries directory.
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3482737Z Setting local variables.
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3492744Z Create the initial timeline records for the tasks
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3512737Z Preparing repositories
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3522741Z repo clean = False
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3522741Z Found 2 endpoints to consider
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3692726Z Found 1 repositories to sync
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3822789Z Starting: Get sources
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3872730Z build.fetchtags=false
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3922753Z Entering GitSourceProvider.PrepareRepositoryAsync
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3932745Z Repository type=TfsGit
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3932745Z localPath=C:\a\1\s
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3942746Z clean=False
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3942746Z sourceBranch=refs/heads/master
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3952739Z sourceVersion=60e5e7f72e94016da7c2de37c839a015656f803c
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3952739Z Syncing repository: SampleWebApiE2ERelease (Git)
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3962739Z repository url=https://*******.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_git/SampleWebApiE2ERelease
2016-04-19T21:51:19.3982738Z checkoutSubmodules=False
2016-04-19T21:51:19.6062900Z Starting clone
2016-04-19T21:51:21.3684519Z Checking out 60e5e7f72e94016da7c2de37c839a015656f803c to C:\a\1\s
2016-04-19T21:51:21.5500305Z Checked out branch refs/heads/master for repository SampleWebApiE2ERelease at commit 60e5e7f72e94016da7c2de37c839a015656f803c
2016-04-19T21:51:21.5510565Z Leaving GitSourceProvider.PrepareRepositoryAsync
2016-04-19T21:51:21.5720503Z Leaving OnPrepareEnvironment
2016-04-19T21:51:21.7216514Z Running tasks
2016-04-19T21:51:21.7586505Z Starting task: Run Tests bin\Release\AcceptanceTest.dll on *************************.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com
2016-04-19T21:51:21.9697226Z Executing the powershell script: C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.98.1\tasks\RunVisualStudioTestsusingTestAgent\1.0.33\RunDistributedTests.ps1
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3211330Z ##[debug]Entering script RunDistributedTests.ps1
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3241378Z ##[debug]TestMachineGroup = *************************.australiaeast.cloudapp.azure.com
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3251318Z ##[debug]Test Drop Location = C:\AcceptanceTests\SampleWebApiE2ERelease
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3251318Z ##[debug]Source Filter = bin\Release\AcceptanceTest.dll
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3261325Z ##[debug]Test Filter Criteria = 
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3271314Z ##[debug]RunSettings File = C:\AcceptanceTests\SampleWebApiE2ERelease\AcceptanceTest.runsettings
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3271314Z ##[debug]Build Platform = 
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3281422Z ##[debug]Build Configuration = 
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3291320Z ##[debug]CodeCoverage Enabled = false
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3291320Z ##[debug]TestRun Parameters to override = 
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3301320Z ##[debug]TestConfiguration = 
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3321302Z ##[debug]Application Under Test Machine Group = 
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3531325Z ##[debug]Loading module from path 'C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.98.1\agent\worker\Modules\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Common\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Common.dll'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3681296Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Complete-Task'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3681296Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Get-LocalizedString'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3691292Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Set-TaskVariable'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3691292Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Set-TaskProgress'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3691292Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Add-TaskIssue'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3701295Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Write-TaskDetail'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3701295Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Find-Files'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3841314Z ##[debug]Loading module from path 'C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.98.1\agent\worker\Modules\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.Internal.dll'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3901295Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Add-BuildAttachment'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3901295Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Convert-String'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3911318Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Get-IndexedSourceFilePaths'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3911318Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Get-JavaDevelopmentKitPath'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3921318Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Get-MSBuildLocation'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3921318Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Get-ServiceEndpoint'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3931319Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Get-TfsClientCredentials'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3941311Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Get-ToolPath'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3941311Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Get-TaskVariable'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3951312Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Get-VisualStudioPath'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3951312Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Get-VssConnection'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3961310Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Invoke-Ant'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3961310Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Invoke-BatchScript'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3971305Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Invoke-Maven'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3971305Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Invoke-MSBuild'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3981310Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Invoke-PublishSymbols'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3981310Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Invoke-Tool'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3991312Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Invoke-VSTest'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.3991312Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Publish-BuildArtifact'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.4001333Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Copy-BuildArtifact'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.4001333Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Add-BuildArtifactLink'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.4011309Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Register-XamarinLicense'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.4011309Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Unregister-XamarinLicense'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.4011309Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Get-X509Certificate'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.4141314Z ##[debug]Loading module from path 'C:\LR\MMS\Services\Mms\TaskAgentProvisioner\Tools\agents\1.98.1\agent\worker\Modules\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DTA\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DTA.dll'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.4351328Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Invoke-DeployTestAgent'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.4361318Z ##[debug]Importing cmdlet 'Invoke-RunDistributedTests'.
2016-04-19T21:51:22.4381326Z ##[debug]Getting the connection object
2016-04-19T21:51:23.2196120Z ##[debug]UnregisterTestAgent script Path  = 
2016-04-19T21:51:23.2206119Z ##[debug]Calling Invoke-RunDistributedTests
2016-04-19T21:51:23.3495532Z ##[debug]Invoking Run Distributed Tests with Register Environment support
2016-04-19T21:51:23.5023828Z ##[warning]For troubleshooting, refer http://aka.ms/remotevstest.
2016-04-19T21:51:23.5171330Z ##[error]System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to get teamfoundation Collection Uri. Contact your administrator for more information.
2016-04-19T21:51:23.5181352Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.RunTests.Run()
2016-04-19T21:51:23.5191312Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.TaskRunner.Run(Dictionary`2 arguments, VssConnection connection, TaskType taskType)
2016-04-19T21:51:23.5201289Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Task.DistributedTestAutomation.RundistributedTestsCmdLet.ProcessRecord()
2016-04-19T21:51:23.5669478Z Finishing task: RunVisualStudioTestsusingTestAgent
2016-04-19T21:51:23.5679492Z ##[error]System.Exception: Task RunVisualStudioTestsusingTestAgent failed. This caused the job to fail. Look at the logs for the task for more details.
2016-04-19T21:51:23.5689495Z ##[error]   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.DistributedTask.Worker.JobRunner.Run(IJobContext jobContext, IJobRequest job, IJobExtension jobExtension, CancellationTokenSource tokenSource)
2016-04-19T21:51:23.5719485Z Entering OnFinalizeJob
2016-04-19T21:51:23.5739469Z Leaving OnFinalizeJob
```

**UPDATE 4**

I changed the tasks in the BUILD so that the tasks are;

```
NuGet Installer

Visual Studio Build

Visual Studio Test (unit tests)

Index Sources & Publish Symbols

Copy And Publish Build Artifacts

Azure File Copy

Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment

Run Functional Tests
```

The "Run Functional Tests" worked.

I then removed the 3 tasks Azure File Copy, Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment, Run Functional Tests from the BUILD, as I dont want the acceptance tests as part of the BUILD, but as part of the RELEASE.

I then changed my RELEASE tasks so they are;

```
Azure File Copy

Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment

Run Functional Tests
```

That worked.

I then disabled the task Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment because the agent is now deployed on the VM and the task takes a little while to run.

That failed, it seems that Run Functional Tasks requires a preceding task Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment.

Is that a bug with Run Functional Tests?  Should you be able to configure your own VM with a Test Agent already installed?

Comment: Could you share a screenshot of Run Functional Tests task setting?

Comment: One more question, if you run the tasks under BUILD tab, will you also see this error?

Comment: Is the machine you specified the same in "Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment" and "Run Functional Tests" task? Can you try running "Azure File Copy" task first and then run "Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment" and "Run Functional Tests" task? And for your Update 3, Run Functional Test need to be preceded with “Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment” task, you may need add "Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment" task in front of "Run Functional Test" task and then try again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Run Functional Tests" tasks needs to be preceded with “Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment” task.

“Visual Studio Test Agent Deployment” task will deploy “Test Agent” to all the machines and configures them automatically for the automation run. If the agent is already available and configured on the machines, this task will be a no-op.

Check: https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/tree/master/Tasks/RunDistributedTests